# How to implement strategy pattern using a strategy that have another one inside?

Tags: java, design-patterns, strategy-pattern

Im implementing a strategy pattern and in a specific situation, one strategy must use another strategy implementation as part of it.

For Example:

```
interface ProcessStrategy{

    void process();

}

public class ProcessOnFile implements ProcessStrategy{

    void process(){


    }
}

public class ProcessOnFileNetwork implements ProcessStrategy{

    void process(){


    }
}
```

In this case, processOnFileNetwork will encapsulate the logic inside ProcessOnFile plus some especific logic..

How can i add this functionality without repeat the code??

Thanks !

Comment: @bot.. its just an example....

Comment: SO expects you to provide MCV code. Anyway, looks like you edited it after my comment so all good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use abstract class concept.

```
public abstract class ProcessStrategy{
    public void process(){
        // Common code goes here
    }

}

public class ProcessOnFile extends ProcessStrategy{

    public void process(){
        super();
        // Class specific code goes here
    }
}

public class ProcessOnFileNetwork extends ProcessStrategy{

    public void process(){
        super();
        // Class specific code goes here
    }
}
```

Note abstract classes can have data variables too which can be utilized.

Comment: Ok, thanks.. can i have more than one operations inside that? for example, process(), checkProcess(), formatProcess()? Maybe mix it with template method??

Comment: Yes you can. Please read on abstract classes will give you a clear picture.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `ProcessOnFileNetwork` a subclass of `ProcessOnFile`.  That way, you can access the logic in the `process()` method of `ProcessOnFile` by calling `super.process()` in the `process()` method of `ProcessOnFileNetwork`.

You probably just typed your code in your question, but just in case, `interface` and `implements` must be all lowercase.